# SDN: Sending a packet from Ryu controller directly to host

Tags: hidden, sdn, ryu

Is it possible to send a data packet from controller directly to the host? I'm using a Ryu controller in my application and I want to create the *covert channel* where I can send some data between controller and host.

Comment: You can send a packet from a switch connected to the host to its output interface to the host, through the controller. Is that OK for you?

Comment: Controllers communicate with openflow switches via southbound interface and communicate with applications via northbound interface. If you consider your host as an application you can use northbound interface but i'm not sure you mean that. If i understand right, your scenario is not fit with openflow.

Comment: @Marievi Yes but in your case the packet is sending from host to controller but I want to make a symmetric channel. Unfortunately OPF specification doesnt anticipated kind of communication which i want to reach.

Comment: Ryu controller has no direct connection to any host. The controller sets up TCP connections with the switches. The switches are connected to hosts. This is NOT an OFP specification limitation, rather how the SDN network works.